# Bug! Copy duplicate json data in fragment on Android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I want show 3 `fragments` in my `Activity` and load data from **`json`** in any `fragments`! I want show each json data into one fragment, but in my application copy duplicate json data in fragment one ! 
**For example :** when running application show 1 post in any `fragment` but when swipe between tabs copy **json** data below posts!

**myEvent (custom eventBus code) :**

```
public class MyEvent {
    public String fragmentTag ;
    private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList();

    public MyEvent (String tag,List<DataModel> models){
        this.fragmentTag = tag;
        this.infoModels = models;
    }

    public List<DataModel> getInfoModels() {
        return infoModels;
    }
}
```

**Fragment 1 codes:**

```
public class free_fragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private free_recycler_adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_free_layout, container, false);

        context = getContext();

        LoadData();

        ///----- RecyclerView -----
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdf_RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter = new free_recycler_adapter(context, dataModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        return view;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
        List<DataModel> dataModels = event.getInfoModels();

        if (event.fragmentTag.equals("forfragment1")) {
            mAdapter.add(dataModels);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        freeDataInfo dataInfo = new freeDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getFreeDataInfo(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**Fragment 1 AsyncTask codes:**

```
public class freeDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = freeServer_IP.getFreeIP();

    public void getFreeDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "limit=10");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            this.dialog.setMessage("شکیبا باشید...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            //String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "limit=10")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("result");

                        for (int i = 0; i <= postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);

                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            Log.d("id", String.valueOf(id));
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String description = postObject.getString("description");
                            String image = postObject.getString("image");
                            String category = postObject.getString("categoryName");
                            String date = postObject.getString("publishDate");

                            Log.d("Data", "Post ID: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post image: " + image);
                            Log.d("Data", "---------------------------------");

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new DataModel(id, title, description, category, date, image));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error2", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();

            //Stop Progress
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(new MyEvent("forfragment1", infoModels));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other fragments codes such as fragment one code!

How to fix this problem and not copy (duplicate) json datas below posts??! Thanks all <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You Clear `ArrayList` Than Add Data In `ArrayList` in Every Call of `AsyncTask`

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            this.dialog.setMessage("شکیبا باشید...");
            this.dialog.show();
            infoModels.clear();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks my bro, but copy data again! your above code not work me :(

Comment: Please check the Size or ArrayList when data come for Server

Comment: I checked this, in server has just one post! but when swipe between in tabs copy this post again!!!